# Display Text and animation on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to find but I cannot find the exact guide so I am here to get your help guys.

I am trying to build animation and text appear on click. for example  when user click on button he will see 3 text appear one after another and then page redirects to another page. Right now my page is redirecting to new page for which I am using PHP. I want to create animation effect too and then page loads.

here is my code for button

```
<button id="btn" name="submit">Button</button>
```

i want when user click on this button it should display 3 **Hey**.. then disappear **Welcome to our website**..then disappear **Enjoy** and after that page should load.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should help you:

```
$('#clickMe').toggle(
            function(){
                $('#textBox1').show()
                $('#textBox2').show();
                 $('#textBox3').show();
                   });
```

And set the transition in CSS to 0.5s:

```
transition-delay: all 0.5s
```

Comment: looks great. how can I set bg color too?

Comment: in style of a label add "background-color: _____ "

Comment: not working above code. it display even without clicking on the button